# How to obtain Brier Score in Random Forest in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I am having trouble getting the Brier Score for my Machine Learning Predictive models. The outcome "y" was categorical (1 or 0). Predictors are a mix of continuous and categorical variables.

I have created four models with different predictors, I will call them "model_1"-"model_4" here (except predictors, other parameters are the same). Example code of my model is:

```
Model_1=rfsrc(y~ ., data=TrainTest, ntree=1000,
         mtry=30, nodesize=1, nsplit=1, 
         na.action="na.impute", nimpute=3,seed=10,
         importance=T)
```

When I run the "Model_1" function in R, I got the results:
[image]

My question was how can I get the predicted possibility for those 412 people? And how to find the observed probability for each person? Do I need to calculate by hand? I found the function `BrierScore()` in "DescTools" package.

But I tried "`BrierScore(Model_1)`", it gives me no results.

codes I added:

```
library(scoring)
library(DescTools)
BrierScore(Raw_SB)
class(TrainTest$VL_supress03)

TrainTest$VL_supress03_nu<-as.numeric(as.character(TrainTest$VL_supress03))
class(TrainTest$VL_supress03_nu)


prediction_Raw_SB = predict(Raw_SB, TrainTest)

BrierScore(prediction_Raw_SB, as.numeric(TrainTest$VL_supress03) - 1)
BrierScore(prediction_Raw_SB, as.numeric(as.character(TrainTest$VL_supress03)) - 1)
BrierScore(prediction_Raw_SB, TrainTest$VL_supress03_nu - 1)
```

I tried some codes: have so many error messages:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One assumption I am making about your approach is that you want to compute the BrierScore on the data you train your model on (which is usually not the correct approach, google train-test split if you need more info there).
In general, therefore you should reflect on whether your approach is correct there.

The `BrierScore` method in `DescTools` only has a defined method for `glm` models, otherwise, it expects as input a vector of predicted probabilities and a vector of true values (see `?BrierScore`).

What you would need to do though is to predict on your data using:

`prediction = predict(model_1, TrainTest, na.action="na.impute")`

and then compute the brier score using

`BrierScore(as.numeric(TrainTest$y) - 1, prediction$predicted[, 1L])`

(Note, that we transform `TrainTest$y` into a numeric vector of 0's and 1's in order to compute  the brier score.)

**Note**: The `randomForestSRC` package also prints a normalized brier score when you call `print(prediction)`.

In general, using one of the available workbenches for machine learning in R (mlr3, tidymodels, caret) might simplify this approach for you and prevent a lot of errors in this direction. This is a really good practice, especially if you are less experienced in ML as it can prevent many errors.

See e.g. [this chapter in the mlr3 book](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/train-predict.html) for more information.

For reference, here is some very similar code using the `mlr3` package, automatically also taking care of train-test splits.

```
data(breast, package = "randomForestSRC") # with target variable "status"
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3extralearners)
task = TaskClassif$new(id = "breast", backend = breast, target = "status")
algo = lrn("classif.rfsrc", na.action = "na.impute", predict_type = "prob")
resample(task, algo, rsmp("holdout", ratio = 0.8))$score(msr("classif.bbrier"))
```

Comment: Thank you! It still not working, I converted the outcome to numeric, and even cannot find the function BrierScore.

Comment: please see the original post, I added more codes and updates